# Java Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android

I try to connect with WiFi module, but i have unfortunately error. It is in 102 line that is:

```
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(getRequest); // execute the request
```

Here is my all code:

```
public class WiFi extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public final static String PREF_IP = WiFiComuncation.PREF_IP;
public final static String PREF_PORT = WiFiComuncation.PREF_PORT;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
public static final String RESPONSE = "Response";
private String serverResponse = "ERROR"; // Ustawiam na domyslny blad problemu z polaczeniem z modułem WiFI
private String ipAddress, portNumber;
private String parameterValue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ipAddress=PREF_IP;
    portNumber=PREF_PORT;
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("HTTP_HELPER_PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(PREF_IP, "192.168.4.1"); // set the ip address value to save
    editor.putString(PREF_PORT, "80"); // set the port number to save
    editor.commit(); // save the IP and PORT
    serverResponse = sendRequest(parameterValue,ipAddress,portNumber); // wysyłam zapytanie do mikrokloca
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    parameterValue = intent.getStringExtra("parameterValue");
    checkAnswer(serverResponse);
    prepareResponse();
    finish();
}

private void prepareResponse() { // Zwracam odpowiedz
    String response = serverResponse;
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.putExtra(RESPONSE, response);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
}

private boolean checkAnswer( String response )
{
    if(response.equals("E001")) // problem z polaczeniem z WiFi
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "#E001 - Błąd połączenia urządzenia z modułem WiFi! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Wyswitlanie komunikatu na apce
        return false;
    }
    if(response.equals("E002")) // Błędny odcisk palca
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "#E002 - Błędny odcisk palca! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Wyswitlanie komunikatu na apce
        return false;
    }
    if(response.equals("E003")) //Błąd komunikacji pomiędzy podzespołami
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "#E001 - Błąd komunikacji pomiędzy podzespołami! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // Wyswitlanie komunikatu na apce
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Description: Send an HTTP Get request to a specified ip address and port.
 * Also send a parameter "parameterName" with the value of "parameterValue".
 * @param parameterValue the pin number to toggle
 * @param ipAddress the ip address to send the request to
 * @param portNumber the port number of the ip address
 * @return The ip address' reply text, or an ERROR message is it fails to receive one
 */

public String sendRequest(String parameterValue, String ipAddress, String portNumber) {
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); // create an HTTP client
        // define the URL e.g. http://myIpaddress:myport/?pin=13 (to toggle pin 13 for example)
        URI website = new URI("http://"+ipAddress+":"+portNumber+"/?"+"pin"+"="+"11");
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(website); // create an HTTP GET object
        getRequest.setURI(website); // set the URL of the GET request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(getRequest); // execute the request
        // get the ip address server's reply
        InputStream content = null;
        content = response.getEntity().getContent();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                content
        ));
        serverResponse = in.readLine();
        // Close the connection
        content.close();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // HTTP error
        serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // IO error
        serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // URL syntax error
        serverResponse = e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return the server's reply/response text
    return serverResponse;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

}

And there is LogCat:

```
> 04-11 14:51:24.399 7540-7540/com.example.iorwet.thoghtaplication
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                    Process: com.example.iorwet.thoghtaplication, PID: 7540
>                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example.iorwet.thoghtaplication/com.example.iorwet.thoghtaplication.WiFi}:
> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                        at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
>                                                                                        at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>                                                                                        at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                        at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
>                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>                                                                                        at
> android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
>                                                                                        at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
>                                                                                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
>                                                                                        at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
>                                                                                        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
>                                                                                        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
>                                                                                        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)
>                                                                                        at
> org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
>                                                                                        at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
>                                                                                        at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>                                                                                        at
> org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>                                                                                        at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>                                                                                        at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>                                                                                        at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>                                                                                        at
> org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>                                                                                        at com.example.iorwet.thoghtaplication.WiFi.sendRequest(WiFi.java:102)
>                                                                                        at com.example.iorwet.thoghtaplication.WiFi.onCreate(WiFi.java:47)
>                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>                                                                                        at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>                                                                                        at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
>                                                                                        at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
>                                                                                        at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                        at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
>                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
>                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: of course you will get this `Exception`. You have to execute the network call in `AsyncTask` in `doInBackground()`

Comment: Yes, my big mistake, thanks for help ;)